# Vectorising or Using Multiprocessing on a Large Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, vectorization

I have a weird dataframe where there are amounts for theoretical deposits up to Day30, so 30 triplets of columns. I want to gather all the data into one single column, where I have all the dates and deposits, regardless of if they happened on Day1,Day2 or DayX for that player. I have tried the following code, which gives a correct output, but takes over >120 mins to run on a large dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame with Day 1 and Day 2 data
data = {
    'Day_date_1': ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-02'],
    'Day_date_1_week_year': ['2024-W01', '2024-W01'],
    'Day1_deposit': [100, 200],
    'Day_date_2': ['2024-01-02', '2024-01-03'],
    'Day_date_2_week_year': ['2024-W01', '2024-W01'],
    'Day2_deposit': [150, 250],
    'PLAYER_ID': [1, 2],
}


date_columns = [f'Day_date_{i}' for i in range(1, 3)]  # Includes Day 1 and Day 2
deposit_columns = [f'Day{i}_deposit' for i in range(1, 3)]  # Includes Day 1 and Day 2
deposit_week_columns = [f'Day_date_{i}_week_year' for i in range(1, 3)]  # Includes Day 1 and Day 2

# Empty DataFrame to store results
result_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Processing the DataFrame
for date_col, week_col, value_col in zip(date_columns, deposit_week_columns, deposit_columns):
    temp_df = df[[date_col, week_col, value_col, "PLAYER_ID"]]
    temp_df.columns = ["deposit_date", 'deposit_week', "deposit_amount", "PLAYER_ID"]
    result_df = result_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)

result_df['deposit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['deposit_date'])
result_deposit = result_df.groupby(['PLAYER_ID', 'deposit_date', 'deposit_week'])['deposit_amount'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'deposit_amount': 'mean_deposit_amount'})

# Output the result
print(result_deposit)
```

Is there any way to vectorise the loop or speeding up processing through multiprocessing?

The output I want is as follows:

```
PLAYER_ID   deposit_date    deposit_week    mean_deposit_amount
1              2024-01-01     2024-W01            100.0
1              2024-01-02     2024-W01            150.0
2              2024-01-02     2024-W01            200.0
2              2024-01-03     2024-W01            250.0
```

Comment: You can `concat` each column of day 1 triplet with day 2 triplet until day 30 triplet. The `PLAYER_ID` column must be concatenated with itself 30 times. Finally you only have to rename the columns and sort the dataframe. This should be fast as it is mainly copying data in memory.

Comment: Isn't that what the for loop in my code is doing? That is the part that seems to take a really long time, >100mins. I think it is due to my dataframe having >16m rows but I don't know how to possibly speed it up.

Comment: Basically yes but in Python code row by row. `concat` runs in compiled binary code and processes the whole data of each column at once.

Comment: amazing! so something like: 

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
for date_col, week_col, value_col in zip(date_columns, withdrawal_week_columns,withdrawal_columns):
    
    result_df = result_df.concat([date_col,value_col,week_col,'PLAYER_ID'])

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with a bit of pre- and post-processing of the column names:

```
out = (
 pd.wide_to_long(df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace(r'_?(\d+)_(week_year|deposit)',
                                                    r'_\2_\1', regex=True),
                             axis=1),
                 stubnames=['Day_date', 'Day_date_week_year', 'Day_deposit'],
                 i='PLAYER_ID', j='j',
                 sep='_')
   .reset_index('PLAYER_ID')
   .rename(columns={'Day_date': 'deposit_date',
                    'Day_date_week_year': 'deposit_week',
                    'Day_deposit': 'mean_deposit_amount',
                   })
   .sort_values(by=['PLAYER_ID', 'deposit_date'])
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   PLAYER_ID deposit_date deposit_week  mean_deposit_amount
0          1   2024-01-01     2024-W01                  100
1          1   2024-01-02     2024-W01                  150
2          2   2024-01-02     2024-W01                  200
3          2   2024-01-03     2024-W01                  250
```